# antlr4, trivial grammar, token recognition errors

Tags: parsing, antlr4

As a complete beginner in antlr4, I haven't been able to make any use of the answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369606/token-recognition-error-antlr). It looks to me that fragments are only called in my grammar by terminal rules, but still the parser is throwing the following error when submitted the string "myIdentifier":

```
line 1:0 token recognition error at: 'm'
line 1:1 token recognition error at: 'y'
line 1:2 token recognition error at: 'I'
line 1:3 token recognition error at: 'd'
line 1:4 token recognition error at: 'e'
line 1:5 token recognition error at: 'n'
line 1:6 token recognition error at: 't'
line 1:7 token recognition error at: 'i'
line 1:8 token recognition error at: 'f'
line 1:9 token recognition error at: 'i'
line 1:10 token recognition error at: 'e'
line 1:11 token recognition error at: 'r'
```

My grammar is this:

```
grammar Sable;

options {

}

@header {
    package org.sable.parser.gen;
}

IDENTIFIER:
    (IdentifierHead IdentifierCharacter*)
    | ('`'(IdentifierHead IdentifierCharacter*)'`')
    ;

WS  :  [ \u0020\u000C\u000A\u000D\u0009u000B\u000C]+ -> skip
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

LINE_COMMENT
    :   '//' ~[\u000A\u000D]* -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;




// NOTE: a file with zero statements is allowed because
// it can contain just comments.
sourceFile:
    statement* EOF;

statement:
    expression ';'?;

// Req. not existing any valid expression starting from
// an equals sign or any other assignment operator.
expression:
    valuedExpression (assignmentOperator valuedExpression)?;

valuedExpression:
    IDENTIFIER
    ;

assignmentOperator:
    '='
    | '*='
    | '/='
    | '%='
    | '+='
    | '-='
    | '<<='
    | '>>='
    | '&='
    | '^='
    | '|='
    ;

fragment DecimalDigit:
    '0'..'9'
    ;

fragment IdentifierHead:
    'a'..'z'
    | 'A'..'Z'
    | '_'
    | '\u00A8'
    | '\u00AA'
    | '\u00AD'
    | '\u00AF' |
    '\u00B2'..'\u00B5' |
    '\u00B7'..'\u00BA'  |
    '\u00BC'..'\u00BE' |
    '\u00C0'..'\u00D6' |
    '\u00D8'..'\u00F6' |
    '\u00F8'..'\u00FF' |
    '\u0100'..'\u02FF' |
    '\u0370'..'\u167F' |
    '\u1681'..'\u180D' |
    '\u180F'..'\u1DBF' |
    '\u1E00'..'\u1FFF' |
    '\u200B'..'\u200D' |
    '\u202A'..'\u202E' |
    '\u203F'..'\u2040' |
    '\u2054' |
    '\u2060'..'\u206F' |
    '\u2070'..'\u20CF' |
    '\u2100'..'\u218F' |
    '\u2460'..'\u24FF' |
    '\u2776'..'\u2793' |
    '\u2C00'..'\u2DFF' |
    '\u2E80'..'\u2FFF' |
    '\u3004'..'\u3007' |
    '\u3021'..'\u302F' |
    '\u3031'..'\u303F' |
    '\u3040'..'\uD7FF' |
    '\uF900'..'\uFD3D' |
    '\uFD40'..'\uFDCF' |
    '\uFDF0'..'\uFE1F' |
    '\uFE30'..'\uFE44' |
    '\uFE47'..'\uFFFD'
    ;
fragment IdentifierCharacter:
    DecimalDigit
    | '\u0300'..'\u036F'
    | '\u1DC0'..'\u1DFF'
    | '\u20D0'..'\u20FF'
    | '\uFE20'..'\uFE2F'
    | IdentifierHead
    ;
```

What am I doing wrongly? My assumptions are:

- **IDENTIFIER** is a terminal
- **IdentifierHead** and **IdentifierCharacter** are
  fragments
- The rest are all parse rules.

Comment: I've changed not the rules completely for a part of a tested grammar I found online, and I'm having the same errors for similar test strings.

Since the only part common to both wrong cases are the options and the @header directives, I guess the error might be caused by them.

Comment: When I test your grammar, `"myIdentifier"` is tokenised as a `IDENTIFIER`. Perhaps you need to regenerate your lexer/parser? With and without the empty `options { }` block it works just fine.

Comment: Hi Bart. Thanks a lot for your input. Well, that makes some sense, at least to the extent that it's my environment what is wrong, not my grammar(s).

I'm using Certiv's Eclipse embedded generator. I will try to do it via a stand-alone installation of antlr4 and see how it goes.

Comment: Well, that was it - I don't know why, but the classes generated by Certiv's plugin just make the test fail for the same grammar.

Thanks again for your comment - it pushed me in the right direction.

There is no top-level answer. Shall I do something to close this question taking your comment as the answer?

Comment: Nice! Feel free to create your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of Bart Kiers' comment:

> When I test your grammar, "myIdentifier" is tokenised as a IDENTIFIER.
>   Perhaps you need to regenerate your lexer/parser? With and without the
>   empty options { } block it works just fine.

it turned out that the problem was in my environment rather than in my grammar. I was using Certiv's antlr4 support plugins for Eclipse to generate my grammar. As soon as I began to generate my grammar using antlr4 from the command line, the errors disappeared.